# SwiftUI NavigationLink still broken in Xcode 11.4 simulators?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm aware of the bug that was supposedly recently fixed in `Xcode 11.4`, where if you ran a simulator with `iOS 13`, the back button for a navigation link wouldn't function correctly. I checked that I'm on 11.4, with the following terminal output,

```
myUser@myUser ~ % /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 11.4
Build version 11E146
```

and yet I'm still having trouble with the back button from `NavigationLink`. I don't have access to a real device to test on, but either way this issue was said to have been fixed. Am I setting up the `NavigationLink` incorrectly?

Here's example code of my setup:

```
//in primary view
NavigationLink(destination: Test()) {
      Text("Hit Me!")
          .fontWeight(.semibold)
          .font(.title)
          .padding()
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(.white),Color(.blue)]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
          .cornerRadius(40)
}
```

```
//the view being navigated to
//I can make it to this page but cannot navigate back
struct Test : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in case someone else makes the same small mistake as myself: `NavigationView` must be the outer most view in your body. I initially had

```
KeyboardHost { //Custom view class
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                 ....
```

Switching to the following fixed the issue

```
NavigationView {
            KeyboardHost {
                VStack {
```

Comment: Thanks! I just ran into this issue. I didn't realize it has to be the outter most view of your body. i wonder if this is just a SwiftUI bug...